# Error in initialising properties file in Jenkins

Tags: windows

I have "OR.properties" properties file in package "com.ma.config" under source folder "src/test/java".  I am using following code to initialize the properties file but it is giving error "Error in initialising propertis file" when I run in jenkins but working fine locally through eclipse. can you please help me in resolving this issue:

```
 static Properties OR;
 public WebConnector(){
    if(OR==null){
        //initialize OR
     try{
         //initilalize OR
         OR = new Properties();
         FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\test\\java\\com\\ma\\config\\OR.properties");
         OR.load(fs);
     }catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println("Error in initialising propertis file");
     }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like classpath issue. 
 Could you please check for Jenkins error logs?

Comment: it's showing "Error in initialising propertis file" when build starts running and giving "Null pointer exception" Error when situation comes to get value from Properties file

Comment: From your explanation, it seems that the properties file cannot be located and read. Try to move the properties file to some simple path like C:\TMP or something like this, and then try again.